# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Post::where()

Tags: php

`A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column`    //I need a useful solution to solve this error , after a couple of hours inves-
     tigating. It's still the same. Is there anyone?

```
function update_post($postID,$data){
    $this->where('postID',$postID); //error line
    $this->db->update('posts',$data);
} 

//code of posts.php
function editpost($postID){
    $data['success']=0;
    if($_POST){
        $data_post=array(
            'title'=>$_POST['title'],
            'post'=>$_POST['post'],
            'active'=>1
        );
        $this->post->update_post($postID,$data); // update_post function
        $data['success']=1;
    }
    $data['post']=$this->post->get_post($postID);
    $this->load->view('edit_post',$data);
}
```

Comment: I just updated $this->where('postID',$postID); //error line to this $this->db->where('postID',$postID); //still thesame

Comment: have you loaded db? i guess you have not neither loaded it manually nor autoloaded it.

Comment: anyways what the error means is that you are trying to work with a column that does not exist in the table..may be a simple typo.

Comment: Thanks praveen will check keep in touch.

Comment: I still get 
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'success' in 'field list'

UPDATE `posts` SET `success` = 0 WHERE `postID` = '6'

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
I dont know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be passing the value of $data_post to the function, but rather $data

```
$data_post=array(
    'title'=>$_POST['title'],
    'post'=>$_POST['post'],
    'active'=>1
);
$this->post->update_post($postID,$data); // update_post function
```

should be:

```
$data_post=array(
    'title'=>$_POST['title'],
    'post'=>$_POST['post'],
    'active'=>1
);
$this->post->update_post($postID,$data_post); // update_post function
```

Comment: Im sorry I got no reputation to do that. Thank you!

Comment: @dirknowitzki, you don't need rep to accept an answer. Click the checkbox on the left. To upvote you will need rep. In fact accepting an answer will increase your rep.